# Arduino 4wd rover

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05, l298n

Guys i have made an arduino 4wd rover using L298N BRIDGE MODULE, HC-05 and Arduino uno but the power supply output of L298N was very low that even 1 motor is working too slow so please help me with power out put please...
Here is the code...

```
#define enA 9
#define in1 4
#define in2 5
#define enB 10
#define in3 6
#define in4 7

int xAxis, yAxis;
int  x = 0;
int  y = 0;

int motorSpeedA = 0;
int motorSpeedB = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(38400); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
}

void loop() {
  // Default value - no movement when the Joystick stays in the center
  xAxis = 510;
  yAxis = 510;

  // Read the incoming data from the Smartphone Android App
  while (Serial.available() >= 2) {
    x = Serial.read();
    delay(10);
    y = Serial.read();
  }
  delay(10);
  
  // Makes sure we receive corrent values
  if (x > 60 & x < 220) {
    xAxis = map(x, 220, 60, 1023, 0); // Convert the smartphone X and Y values to 0 - 1023 range, suitable motor for the motor control code below
  }
  if (y > 60 & y < 220) {
    yAxis = map(y, 220, 60, 0, 1023);
  }

  // Y-axis used for forward and backward control
  if (yAxis < 470) {
    // Set Motor A backward
    digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    // Set Motor B backward
    digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    // Convert the declining Y-axis readings for going backward from 470 to 0 into 0 to 255 value for the PWM signal for increasing the motor speed
    motorSpeedA = map(yAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
    motorSpeedB = map(yAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
  }
  else if (yAxis > 550) {
    // Set Motor A forward
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
    // Set Motor B forward
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
    // Convert the increasing Y-axis readings for going forward from 550 to 1023 into 0 to 255 value for the PWM signal for increasing the motor speed
    motorSpeedA = map(yAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
    motorSpeedB = map(yAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
  }
  // If joystick stays in middle the motors are not moving
  else {
    motorSpeedA = 0;
    motorSpeedB = 0;
  }

  // X-axis used for left and right control
  if (xAxis < 470) {
    // Convert the declining X-axis readings from 470 to 0 into increasing 0 to 255 value
    int xMapped = map(xAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
    // Move to left - decrease left motor speed, increase right motor speed
    motorSpeedA = motorSpeedA - xMapped;
    motorSpeedB = motorSpeedB + xMapped;
    // Confine the range from 0 to 255
    if (motorSpeedA < 0) {
      motorSpeedA = 0;
    }
    if (motorSpeedB > 255) {
      motorSpeedB = 255;
    }
  }
  if (xAxis > 550) {
    // Convert the increasing X-axis readings from 550 to 1023 into 0 to 255 value
    int xMapped = map(xAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
    // Move right - decrease right motor speed, increase left motor speed
    motorSpeedA = motorSpeedA + xMapped;
    motorSpeedB = motorSpeedB - xMapped;
    // Confine the range from 0 to 255
    if (motorSpeedA > 255) {
      motorSpeedA = 255;
    }
    if (motorSpeedB < 0) {
      motorSpeedB = 0;
    }
  }
  // Prevent buzzing at low speeds (Adjust according to your motors. My motors couldn't start moving if PWM value was below value of 70)
  if (motorSpeedA < 70) {
    motorSpeedA = 0;
  }
  if (motorSpeedB < 70) {
    motorSpeedB = 0;
  }
  analogWrite(enA, motorSpeedA); // Send PWM signal to motor A
  analogWrite(enB, motorSpeedB); // Send PWM signal to motor B
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the battery? Are you using geared motors?

Comment: I am using 9v battery and yes it is a geared motor.....

Comment: A wimpy PP3? ...?

Comment: The [9V battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery) is meant for *low power* applications. You will need to find another powersource

Comment: While your primary problem is improper battery selection (try 6 to 8 AA cells) also beware that the L298 (and L293D, etc) is an antiquated, horribly lossy driver.  These really shouldn't be sold for Arduino or other low-voltage projects - they continue to be because people keep copying a mistake that was already wrong even when it was made now many years ago.  Typically when using AA cells and an L298, you need an extra cell or two in the pack just to offset the L298's losses.

Comment: Can i use a powerbank with 10000 Mah battery...?

Comment: @CodeGorilla That question doesn't have an answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You need more power!

The formula for power is Volts * Amps. A PP3 has about 500mAh, which means its can (in theory) output 9V at 500mA for an hour, which means you have about 4.5 watts.

So what power do your motors need? I'll assume they are about 1.5W motors, which means you need 6W to drive all the motors.

Your PP3 can output 6W, but it won't last long if it does and it will get hot.  Also, if you have 12V motors and are only giving the 9V then they are going to be asking for 1/3 more amps to balance the equation and get their power.  You are probably asking the PP3 to supply 1A which means it will last less than 30 minutes if it is brand new and good quality.

A "simple" solution would be to use two (or more) batteries in parallel.  Parallel gives you more power without changing the voltage.  A better solution would be to look at alternative battery packs, a couple or LiPo 3.7V 1100mAh battery packs, a sealed lead acid gel (heavy).  An even better solution would be to see if you can get lower power motors that can supply the same torque.

Failing that, get a meaty desktop power supply and a long cable :)

Comment: Can i use a powerbank with 10000 Mah battery...?

Comment: Maybe -\o/-  It will either work or it won't